# iPad Safari Popup issue

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

On iPad Safari, there seems to be issue with popup. When a popup (opened using window.open()) is closed, it remains in minimized mode (or grid view) after closing the popup...It
does not return focus to the parent window.

I have tried using parent.opener.focus(), but still does not work.

Is this a known iPad issue OR can we fix this issue using some JS code?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would help, but just some personal experience on this issue:

Did you try going to iPad's **Setting - Safari - Block Pop-ups**? Try turning off Block Pop-ups, it should work.

If it still doesn't appear, try turning on the Debug Console for the ipad and check if any error appears during the popup event.

Try using a URL for window.open to be a local / same domain url address. I think that works (without needing to turn off the popup blocker in safari ipad).